# getNamespaceExports() called from within .onLoad package function

Tags: r, scope, namespaces, package, environment

Why does `getNamespaceExports()` return different results when called automatically from `.onLoad` context as opposed to when called from external code?

Let us assume we have an R package called `testpackage`. This package contains a single R file called `hello.R` with the following content:

```
#' @export
package_var <- "some value"

#' @export
call_when_onload <- function(pkgname) {
  print(getNamespaceExports(pkgname))
  print(do.call("getNamespaceExports",list(pkgname),envir = globalenv()))
}

.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname){
  print(sprintf("Executing onload procedure for package %s...",pkgname))
  call_when_onload(pkgname)
}
```

The package has a NAMESPACE file which looks like this:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(call_when_onload)
export(package_var)
```

Now here is the problem: After documenting and building the package, `library("testpackage")` returns this:

```
> library(testpackage)
[1] "Executing onload procedure for package testpackage..."
character(0)
character(0)
```

But when I call `testpackage::call_when_onload("testpackage")`, I get the following output (just as expected):

```
> testpackage::call_when_onload("testpackage")
[1] "package_var"      "call_when_onload"
[1] "package_var"      "call_when_onload"
```

**Why? How can I make the `.onLoad` function evaluate the expressions above just like they evaluated when called from external context?**

Comment: Could it be that `.onLoad` gets executed before exported objects are written to the global environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per `?.onLoad` (emphasis mine):

> After loading, loadNamespace looks for a hook function named .onLoad and calls it (with two unnamed arguments) **before sealing the namespace and processing exports.**

So `.onLoad` runs before anything is exported from your package.

If you want to get all the exported objects, one way is to read the NAMESPACE file from the package and process it:

```
f <- base::system.file("NAMESPACE", package="pkgname")
objs <- readLines(f)
exps <- objs[grepl("export", objs)]
sub("^export[^\\(]*\\(([^\\)]+)\\)", "\\1", exps)
```

Some tweaking may be necessary to match the output of `getNamespaceExports` exactly.